# API Call from App Engine flexible to Firebase FCM failed

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-api, app-engine-flexible

API Calls,e.g. to Firebase https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send worked before switching from `<env>vm</env>` appengine-web.xml to 
`env: flex` app.yaml flexible.

When deploying with `mvn appengine:deploy` everything is fine, but when an API call gets fired, which worked before, i get the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: 
Can't make API call urlfetch.Fetch in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager 
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800) 
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:112) 
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:40) 
at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchRequest.execute(UrlFetchRequest.java:74) 
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981) 
at com.qweez.flexenv.service.GameCounterService.run(GameCounterService.java:80)
```

it crashes when calling request.execute() below:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

// stuff

   try {
           HttpRequest request = HttpRequestUtil.getHttpRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(GlobalConfig.MESSAGING_SERVER_URL), ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", requestBody));
           HttpResponse response = request.execute();


                        //logger.warning(LOG_TAG+" ++++++ response status=" + response.getContent());    
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.warning(LOG_TAG+" sent messge to topic error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
```

the helper class httpRequestUtil looks like this

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpRequestUtil {
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
    private static HttpRequestFactory requestFactory;
    static {
        httpTransport = UrlFetchTransport.getDefaultInstance();
        requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
                HttpHeaders hh = new HttpHeaders();

                hh.setAuthorization(GlobalConfig.SERVER_KEY);
                hh.setContentType("application/json");
                httpRequest.setHeaders(hh);
            }
        });
    }
    public static HttpRequestFactory getHttpRequestFactory(){
        return requestFactory;
    }
```

Is there something deprecated now?
Or what's the issue here now?

Any help very appreciated. Thanks!